# C++ - what type to supply for explicit instantiation of a template function, when std::less is one of the arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

eg. Function header is:

```
template <class comparison_function, class iterator_type, class size_type>
bool F(comparison_function compare, iterator_type it)
```

Call takes `iterator_type` and `comparison_function` parameters, but not size_type. Hence the function call has to be explicit eg.:

```
F<?, std::vector<int>::iterator, long int>(std::less<int>(), it);
```

What would `?` be?

Comment: Don't you just need `std::less<int>`?

Comment: `()` in `std::less<int>()` are empty constructor arguments.

Comment: @OP Note that you're missing a return type from your function template declaration/header.

Comment: If you put `size_type` first in your template parameter list then you could just use `F<long>(std::less<int>{}, it);` and let the compiler deduce `comparison_function` and `iterator_type`.

Comment: That's a strange looking comparison function signature. Why do you need that third template parameter? At least move it to be the first

Comment: Even better, if `size_type` is the iterator's size type, you could just determine it internally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What would ? be?

It should be the type of the first passed argument i.e., `std::less<int>`

```
//vvvvvvvvvvvvvv----------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
F<std::less<int>, std::vector<int>::iterator, long int>(std::less<int>(), it);
```

---

Note that the parenthesis `()` in `std::less<int>()` means that you're passing a **default constructed object** of type `std::less<int>`.

---

##### Sidenote

You can avoid passing two of the template arguments explicitly by making use of **template argument deduction**. This can be done by making `size_type` to be the first template parameter so that the remaining two template parameters can be **deduced** from the passed arguments as shown below:

```
//--------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--------------------------->now size_type is the first template parameter
template <class size_type, class comparison_function, class iterator_type>
void F(comparison_function compare, iterator_type it);

int main()
{
//----------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv---->this uses template argument deduction for the remaining two parameters 
    F<long>(std::less<int>(), it);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid writing the comparator type twice (unless it is something extraordinary):

```
F<std::less<int>, std::vector<int>::iterator, long int>({}, it);
```

The empty braces cause default construction of the comparator object. Its type cannot be deduced from the empty braces, but since it is specified in the template argument list, that does not hurt.